# Plot the magnitude of coefficients against frequencies of DCT transform

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform

When we perform DCT transform using matlab:

```
 number_of_sample_data = 100;
 f=0.1; %frequency
 fs=1; %sampling rate 
 phi_0=0
 t=0:1/fs:((number_of_sample_data-1)*1/fs); %generate 100 samples
 x=sin(2*pi*f*t+phi_0);
dct_transform=dct(x); %perform discrete cosine transform
figure(1), stem(dct_transform);
```

this piece of code will plot the magnitude of coefficients against frequencies or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actuually, that code doesn't work without defining axis t variable, and frequency f, regarding to what that code does, is simple:

```
x=sin(2*pi*f*t);        %x is a sinusoidal vector of frequency f and length t;
dct_transform=dct(x);   %dct_transform is a vector containing the unitary discrete transform of x
figure(1), plot(dct_transform); %plots the the unitary discrete transform of the sinusoid against default axis in Matlab
```

So you are just plotting the discrete transform vector against sample position, wish is what Matlab does by default.

Comment: Sorry i haven't enter all the code. I mean i don't understand when we do 'dct' in matlab what is the output plot? magnitude of coefficients against frequencies or something else? I have enter the full code now.

Comment: Check , my answer again, and comment me if u don't understand

Comment: I think i understand that i need to add more code to do the job. What i need to alter?